# Apparently fine http request results malformed when sent over socket

Tags: python, sockets, http, proxy, httprequest

I'm working with socket operations and have coded a basic interception proxy in python. It works fine, but some hosts return 400 bad request responses.

These requests do not look malformed though. Here's one:

```
GET http://www.baltour.it/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.baltour.it
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Same request, raw:

```
GET http://www.baltour.it/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.baltour.it\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n
```

The code I use to send the request is the most basic socket operation (though I don't think the problem lies there, it works fine with most hosts)

```
socket_client.send(request_raw)
```

while socket_client.recv is used to get the response (but no problems here, the response is well-formed, though its status is 400).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not talking to a proxy, you are not supposed to put the `http://hostname` part in the HTTP header; see [section 5.1.2 of the HTTP 1.1 RFC 2616 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.2):

> The most common form of Request-URI is that used to identify a resource on an origin server or gateway. In this case **the absolute path of the URI MUST be transmitted (see section 3.2.1, abs_path) as the Request-URI**, and the network location of the URI (authority) MUST be transmitted in a Host header field.

(emphasis mine); `abs_path` is the absolute path part of the request URI, not the full absolute URI itself.

E.g. the server expects you to send:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.baltour.it
```

A receiving server should be tolerant of the incorrect behaviour, however. The server seems to violate the RFC as well here too. Further on in the same section it reads:

> To allow for transition to absoluteURIs in all requests in future versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers MUST accept the absoluteURI form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate them in requests to proxies.

Comment: > `the server is perfectly within its rights to respond with a 400 Bad Request status code` This is not true, actually -- even though I too feel it *should* be true: `To allow for transition to the absolute-form for all requests in some future version of HTTP, a server MUST accept the absolute-form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only send them in requests to proxies.` (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.3.2)

Comment: @Will: ah, goodie, 2616 was indeed updated to 7230, and in Sept 2014 I wasn't yet aware of those updates. Certainly, the server the OP talked to wasn't yet updated to the new specs yet *either*.

Comment: I appreciate that you've taking the time to update your answer to be as accurate as possible, so I feel like a bit of an ass pointing this out, but the same paragraph exists in the now obsolete RFC2616 that you originally quoted, albeit with some minor differences in phrasing: `To allow for transition to absoluteURIs in all requests in future versions of HTTP, all HTTP/1.1 servers MUST accept the absoluteURI form in requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only generate them in requests to proxies.` (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.2)

Comment: @Will: why would you need to feel like a bit of an ass for that? It is me that failed to check the old RFC more thoroughly. Will update once more, thanks for being diligent!